# Jest babel setup SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am trying to setup jest in my old project and facing the above issue, where it throws

**SyntaxError: Cannot use import outside a module**

This is my component which i am trying to test

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import get from 'lodash.get';
import { PrimaryButton } from 'fk-cs-component'; // throws error on this lines
```

Below is my **jest.cofig.js**

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.js'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    },
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.js'],
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src/Myntra'],
    collectCoverage: true,
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src/testUtils'],
    // verbose: true,
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 0,
            functions: 0,
            lines: 0,
            statements: 0,
        },
    },
    transform: {
        '\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
        '\\.jsx$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '/node_modules/*'],
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.js$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
};
```

here is the babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: 'auto',
            },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react',
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions',
    ],
};
```

and At last setupTests.js

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies":{
        //other dependencies

        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.12.13",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.3",
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
        "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
        "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-css-modules": "^1.1.0",
   }

}
```

Before you say this is a duplicate of other tickets, I have tried many solutions available over the internet and some how none of them is working for me. thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies with your `fk-cs-component` dependency being an ES module instead of CJS (commonjs). Read more about Javascript modules [here](https://redfin.engineering/node-modules-at-war-why-commonjs-and-es-modules-cant-get-along-9617135eeca1). Since you've told babel not to transform `node_modules` (which is correct, it shouldn't), jest won't handle ES6 `import`/`export` (ESM) syntax and instead expects 3rd party dependencies to be CJS (`require`/`module.exports`).

Comment: @MattCarlotta is there a work around for this? I can not avoid that fk-cs-component as this is an important dependecy.

Comment: You'll have to transpile it for CommonJS. You can do this with a jest rule, or... better yet, compile the source code to CommonJS. Since I haven't seen the `fk-cs-component` code, I can't be of much help.